# Space between windows in ubuntu when placing them side by side ctrl+super+left/right

Tags: 13.10, window

When I put two windows side by side with ctrl+super+left/right there is a small space between both windows where I see the desktop wallpaper, it's kind of annoying and I haven't been able to figure out how to eliminate it or at least reduce it a bit. I'm using ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: It depends what windows do you use. For me it's happen only when I have the terminal on the right side. You are in the same situation?

Comment: It happens with most windows, but if I put my browser on the left and the other window on the right there is no space between the windows but to the right of the screen... it's weird.